# GTK::Socket and Gtk::Plug unexpected behaviour under Gnome and FVWM2

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gtk

The following code works fine if run within FVWM2.  But if you change desktop to Gnome, then the embedded window is destroyed instead of being embedded.

**Why is that?**  What am I missing?...

The code follows but basically all it does is fork. In the child, we create a VPython window an let it idle forever.  In the parent, we create a GTK window, find out what the window ID of the child window is, and try to embed it vis a GTK::Socket.

Note that the VPython part maybe irrelevant to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import re
import time
from visual import *


def find_window_id (title):
    """Gets the OpenGL window ID."""
    pattern = re.compile('0x[0-9abcdef]{7}')
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['xwininfo', '-name', title],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    errors = proc.stderr.readlines()
    if errors:
        return None
    for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
        match = pattern.findall(line)
        if len(match):
            return long(match[0], 16)
    return None



class Setting ():
    """VPython/OpenGL class."""

    def __init__ (self, w=256, h=256, title='OpenGL via VPython'):
        """Initiator."""
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.title = title
        self.scene = display.get_selected() 
        self.scene.title = self.title
        self.scene.width = self.width
        self.scene.height = self.height
        self.sphere = sphere()



class GTKDisplay ():

    def __init__ (self, winID):
        """Initiator: Draws the GTK GUI."""
        import gtk
        import pygtk
        self.OpenGLWindowID = winID
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.show()
        socket = gtk.Socket()
        socket.show()
        window.add(socket)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        socket.add_id(long(self.OpenGLWindowID))
        gtk.main()



def main ():
    """Main entry point."""
    name = 'sphere OpenGL window'
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if 0 == child_pid:
        sut = Setting(title=name)
    else:
        winID = None
        while not winID:
            time.sleep(.1)
            winID = find_window_id(name)
        try:
            gui = GTKDisplay(winID)
        except KeyboardInterrupt, err:
            print '\nAdieu monde cruel!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*PS: Yes, this is a follow up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10934787/232794) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265110/232794).*